# htaccess is not working in two almost identical cases

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This rewriting rule is not working (the id is empty after redirecting):

```
RewriteRule ^album/([0-9]+)$ album.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

while this one does:

```
RewriteRule ^album([0-9]+)$ album.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The removed slash is the only difference.

Comment: I want to match `album/12`. I have no idea why the first rule doesn't work, while the other one matching album12 works.

Comment: Have you tried changing `album.php?id=$1` to `album.php\?id=$1`? I know little about .htaccess, but I have a feeling you need to escape ?.

Comment: No, you definitely don't need to escape the `?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with multiviews. Multiviews bypasses you rewrite rules, because it matched `/album/...` to the existing file `album.php`

You can prevent this by adding `Options -MultiViews` to your htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the way mod_rewrite rules in .htaccess files are processed. Basically, the input to the RewriteRule will only be the "file" portion of the path, so when the URL is `.../album/42`, the `RewriteRule` will be matching against `42`.

The solution is to use a `RewriteCondition` as well. Something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/album/([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1/album.php?id=%2 [L,QSA]
```